# Client-server communication C#

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm writing a project on Blazor WebAssembly hosted on ASP.NET. Project includes Client, Server, Shared parts. On the server side database is getting processed by API Controller, so on the server project I can get the information by "api/[controller]" response. The main question is how can I manage to process server API controller methods on Client side? What kind of instruments are useful in this situation in C#? Can "HttpClient" class can help to get the info from the server side (and if yes, how?). Would really glad to get any help.